# Only first if statement firing

Tags: c#, calculator

So I am working on a 3 digit calculator and for some reason, I can only get it to add and I don't know why. I feel like it will get pointed out to me and I will feel really stupid.

---

```
private void CalcCalcBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)            
    {
        double num1 = double.Parse(calc1Txt.Text);
        double num2 = double.Parse(calc2Txt.Text);
        double num3 = double.Parse(calc3Txt.Text);
        {
            if(calcAddBtn.Enabled == true)
            {
                double output = (num1 + num2 + num3);
                calcOpLbl.Text = output.ToString("0.00");
            }
            else if(calcSubBtn.Enabled == true)
            {
                double output = (num1 - num2 - num3);
                calcOpLbl.Text = output.ToString("0.00");
            }
            else if(calcMutBtn.Enabled == true)
            {
                double output = (num1 * num2 * num3);
                calcOpLbl.Text = output.ToString("0.00");
            }
            else if(calcDivBtn.Enabled == true)
            {
                double output = (num1 / num2 / num3);
                calcOpLbl.Text = output.ToString("0.00");
            }
        }
    }
```

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Enabled` means "is it possible for the user to click this button", not "is this the button that the user just clicked". Since all four of those buttons are always enabled, it's always true for the first, and the `else`s mean that it doesn't bother looking at the rest.

Comment: @OP To add to Joseph's answer, you need to handle the click event of each button individually.

Comment: Well, now I feel stupid. What's the alternative to it? Just leaving it out?

Comment: Like @AhmedAbdelhameed said, you should create methods that handle each button click individually. This way, when you click the `+` button for example, it should run the method dedicated to handling a click on that button

Comment: Thank you for giving me a different view. It works not. I should say against better judgment those buttons were originally radio buttons which is why I had thought about making the code that way.

Comment: @OkamiWilks If they are/were RadioButtons, then your logic was correct but you used the wrong property. You would need to use `RadioButton.Checked` in this case, not `RadioButton.Enabled`. That being said, you would still need to handle the `Click` or the `CheckedChanged` event for each RadioButton individually which would be something like `void RadioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) { DoCalculations(); }` where `DoCalculations()` is a method containing the `if.. else if` logic.